# How to traverse C# LinkedList in reverse order

Tags: c#

How can I do the equivalent of the following C++ snippet using C# `LinkedList`?

```
std::list<MyClass*>::reverse_iterator itr(it); 
for(; itr != MyList.rend(); ++itr)
```

Answer (score 19):

As a 1-off, something like:

```
var el = list.Last;
while (el != null) {
    // use el.Value
    el = el.Previous;
}
```

If you are doing it regularly, maybe a similar iterator block to yield all the values:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Reverse<T>(this LinkedList<T> list) {
    var el = list.Last;
    while (el != null) {
        yield return el.Value;
        el = el.Previous;
    }
}
```

then:

```
foreach(var val in list.Reverse()) {
    // use val
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `LinkedList<T>` is `IEnumerable<T>`, so it picks up `IEnumerable<T>.Reverse()` if you're using Linq. That might suffice for really short lists. For longer lists, the approach in this answer will be more efficient.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge Which one takes precedence if both are available via 'using'? The more specific one?

Comment: @EugenDück Yes, the more specific one (i.e. for `LinkedList<T>`) will take precedence. But *if* the performance of the `IEnumerable<T>` version you get for free is sufficient then you don't need to implement the other one at all.

Comment: For anyone who cares, the extension method is sadly almost twice as slow as the while loop

Comment: @UnionP did you use the BenchmarkDotNet for your benchmarks? Could you share the results?

Comment: I hadn't, but I did just now and the results are even worse, 92ns (extension) vs. 11ns (for loop). You can reproduce them with this LINQPad script: http://share.linqpad.net/j2ojvo.linq

Comment: To clarify though - for virtually 100% of cases, this nanosecond-scale difference should be irrelevant, and the readability of the Reverse() extension method should give it the win

Comment: @UnionP thanks for sharing the results of your benchmark. I hadn't realized that the C# iterators have measurable overhead.

Comment: Marc Gravell you could rename the `Reverse` to `ReverseIteration` or something, to rule out any chance of invoking the LINQ [`Reverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse) operator by mistake. Interestingly there is no much difference in the performance of yours and LINQ's operators. The only observable difference is that the LINQ `Reverse` allocates much more memory.

Answer (score 1):

An tweak to [Marc's while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8193823/892770) is using a for loop, which I find a little cleaner:

```cs
for (var el = list.Last; el != null; el = el.Previous)
{
    // use el.Value
}
```