# Error: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I get the following compilation error at the class name.

`Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

I am not using normal class. What could be the reason for this. I don't know and don't want to use extension methods.

Comment: Without your code there isn't much we can do. My best guess is that you accidentally typed "this" somewhere in a parameter list.

Comment: Please show the method signatures of your class.

Comment: Wow!!!!!! that was the error! thanks a ton!

Comment: @Jules, you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As requested, here is my comment as an answer:

Without your code there isn't much we can do. My best guess is that you accidentally typed "this" somewhere in a parameter list.

Comment: Thaks! helped me alot..i was searching what was done bad..and did not find, until you wrote about THIS..so i've searched "this" and found it in not his place :)

Answer (score 5):

Sample for extension method

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
 public static object ToAnOtherObject(this object obj) {
  // Your operation here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and solved it as follows. My code was something like this:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static object ToAnOtherObject(this object obj) 
    {
        // Your operation here
    }
}
```

and I changed it to

```
public static class ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static object ToAnOtherObject(object obj) 
    {
        // Your operation here
    }
}
```

I removed the word "this" of the parameter of the method.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this relates to your [previous list question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193806/how-to-traverse-c-sharp-linkedlist-in-reverse-order); if so, the example I provided **is** an extension method, and would be:

```
public static class LinkedListUtils { // name doesn't matter, but must be
                                      // static and non-generic
    public static IEnumerable<T> Reverse<T>(this LinkedList<T> list) {...}
}
```

This utility class does not need to be the same as the consuming class, but extension methods is how it is possible to use as `list.Reverse()`

If you don't want it as an extension method, you can just make it a local static method - just take away the "this" from the firstparameter:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Reverse<T>(LinkedList<T> list) {...}
```

and use as:

```
foreach(var val in Reverse(list)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following points need to be considered when creating an extension method:

1. The class which defines an extension method must be *non-generic* and `static`
2. Every extension method must be a `static` method
3. The first parameter of the extension method should use the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

How about posting your code? Extension methods are declared by preceding the first parameter of a static method with this. Since you don't won't to use an extension method, I suspect you accidentally started a parameter list with `this`.

Look for something like:

```
void Method(this SomeType name)
{
}
```